# I got a signal SIGABRT and a log message

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, dictionary, sigabrt

I tried to run my app and I got signal SIGABRT in the Main.m file and this log message. Help?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-     [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "5wY-6u-SFr-view-Zew-TR-1Cy" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15d3052 0x1764d0a 0x157ba78 0x157b9e9 0x2536ae 0xea5cb 0xf358c 0xee3e8 0x307cc5 0xf1427      0xf158c 0xb6f5280 0xf15cc 0x4546b6 0x448e30 0x15d4ec9 0x275c2 0x2755a 0xccb76 0xcd03f 0xcc2fe    0x4ca30 0x4cc56 0x33384 0x26aa9 0x14bdfa9 0x15a71c5 0x150c022 0x150a90a 0x1509db4 0x1509ccb    0x14bc879 0x14bc93e 0x24a9b 0x1d42 0x1cb5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here is the code for my table view:

```
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.menu count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Title"];
        return cell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController"bundle:nil];
    OrderViewController *orderViewController = [[OrderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"orderViewController"bundle:nil];    
    detailViewController.item = [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    orderViewController.itemString = [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Seems like your tableView isn't connected to your outlet.

Comment: Or the xib is somehow corrupted.

Comment: How would you connect the tableview to an outlet?

Comment: May be your tableview is loading from nib so connect your tableview name with nib file.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen same problem as mentioned by Hot Licks. My xib file got corrupted. You can define corruption of xib as for example, a control is wired to more than one actions, or wired with  couple of ivars. Obviously, by mistake.

Fastest thing to check your xib file,right click on control and see whether it has more than one association.